# Control system transfer function

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, homework

I tried to find the transfer function F(s) = C(s)/R(s) through block manipulation and through Mason's Formula but the results are not matching. Where is the mistake?

[image]

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4OCU.png) won't help you apply block manipulation. But it will help you check your results.

Answer (score 2):

I can't (and won't) spot your mistake with the way you have presented your work. I will instead teach you the easiest way to solve these block diagram problems. Move the feed-forward branch behind G1 (that's the one giving you trouble) and add an 1/G1 block to make the block diagram easier to work with.

[image]

Now use the formula \$G_{cl} = \frac{G_{forward}}{1+G_{ol}}\$ 3 times (because there are 3 feedback loops) each time replacing a loop with one transfer function block.

Doing all of this will leave you with one transfer function block.

[image]

Comment: I did exactly that on the second page in my picture and the result checks out. The issue now is with my solution through Mason's Formula (the first page in my picture) - it's not matching with the other solution.